# Encoding video for PS4 Pro using ffmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg, ps4

I'm trying to encode video to watch on my PS4 Pro (so want to be able to handle 4k as well as 1080p).

At first I had success with the default ffmpeg .mp4 command just using this:

ffmpeg -i .mkv .mp4

This was fine for the first batch of 1080p videos I encoded. But, then it started to fail me - the videos would encode but when I tried to watch them on the PS4 the file would start to play with only audio, no video, play for a few seconds then fail and become unusable.

I checked and apparently the PS4 requires the H.264 codec. So, I installed libx264-dev and tried:

ffmpeg -i .mkv -vcodec libx264 .mp4

I got the same result - the video encoded and started to play on the PS4 with only audio then failed.

Any suggestions for what I am missing / doing wrong? This is the first time for me to use ffmpeg so I am not familiar with its various features / parameters. I'm running Ubuntu 22.04.